# How to join to an alias column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, alias

I have the followig problem. When the input is empty I want to replace it with the 'yellow_code' column aliased as 'Code'.  When I attempt an inner join on the aliased column 'Code' to 'GrantCode' on another table, I get the following error description: "Invalid column name 'Code'".

Anyways to bypass this?

Comment: Could you post your query?  You are likely defining your alias in the same query that you are trying to use it in a `JOIN`, you need to either put the alias in a subquery or use the `CASE` statement in your `JOIN`

Comment: yes, the alias is being defined in the same query I used the case statement in the join instead.

Comment: Another common way to deal with this is via a CTE:  ;With subquery AS (SELECT blah from First Table) SELECT * FROM subquery INNER JOIN otherQuery ON blah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SELECT-column alias is practically the last thing to be applied to the statement and as such is not available for joins "lower down" that form part of the query as a whole. You can however access the alias if referenced from an outer select

e.g.

```
select my_code from
(
select 1 as my_code from ....
) x
```